# Using set interval and fetch in a function

Tags: javascript, setinterval, fetch-api

Create a function `startShowingMessage` that takes two parameters: an element and a string that is a URL. The function will use `setInterval` to make the following task every 1s: fetch the URL and put the response text into the text content of the provided element.

I made the function and the fetch works, but i don't know how to set interval in the same function, without having to call another function.

```js
async function startShowingMessage(elem, url){
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const text = await response.text();
  elem.textContent = text;
}
```

The functions works partially because there is no interval.

Comment: You do not want to call something every second. That is hammering the server. You should call setTimeout in the resolve function

Answer (score 4):

you can use `setInterval` for your need

```
function startShowingMessage(elem, url){
  setInterval(async function(){
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const text = await response.text();
    elem.textContent = text;
  }, 1000);     
}
```

if you want to learn more about it [here it is on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Or the official documentation can be found [here on MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals#setInterval()) as suggested by 3limin4t0r

Comment: Move the `async` keyword from the `startShowingMessage` function to the anonymous function passed to `setInterval` and this answer is correct.

Comment: As a side note check out [Why not w3schools.com?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com). For JavaScript most people will refer to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). In this case a reference to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals#setInterval()) would suffice.

Comment: added the official documentation link from MDN, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Call the function every 1 second:

```
setInterval(startShowingMessage, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function startShowingMessage(elem, url) {
  setInterval(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
    
    elem.textContent = response.message
  }, 1000)
}
```