# Read json data from url and display response in Node js

Tags: node.js, json

How to read json data from url and display in node js. How can i read json data from URL below and customize into my route api.

URL: [www.test.com/jsondata](http://www.test.com/jsondata)

```
{
   "test1": {
     "symbol": "test1"
    },
     "test2": {
     "symbol": "test2"
    },
}
```

Please find route api below:

```
router.get("/test", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: "data" }));
```

Result:

```
When run localhost/test

Data will display json format by reading from URL above.

Example(Data from URL):

{
   "test1": {
     "symbol": "test1"
    },
     "test2": {
     "symbol": "test2"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
router.get("/test", async (req, res) => {
  await fetch(URL)
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((data) => res.json({ msg: data }))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

Replace the URL with the url from which you are fetching the json.

Comment: Can set timer to request URL every 1 hour per request ?

Comment: Yes. You can use setInterval for that purpose. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58663713/using-set-interval-and-fetch-in-a-function#:~:text=Create%20a%20function%20startShowingMessage%20that,content%20of%20the%20provided%20element.)